# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos de una lista anidada teniendo sus índices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

Tengo la lista de listas `palabras` y tengo la lista `indices`. Lo que estoy intentando es eliminar las sublistas que contienen `''` de `palabras` con lo cual tengo los índices de dichas sublistas en `indices` de manera que al final al imprimir palabras su resultado en pantalla sea `[['carro rojo'],['avion']]`.

Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
palabras = [['carro rojo'],[''],[''],['avion'],['']]
indices = [1,2,4]

for i in range(len(indices)):
    palabras.pop(indices[i])

print(palabras)
```

Pero en consola solo obtengo el siguiente error:

```
palabras.pop(indices[2])
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Y de igual forma si lo hago de manera manual sin el ciclo `for` de tal forma que el código quedaría como:

```
palabras = [['carro rojo'],[''],[''],['avion'],['']]
indices = [1,2,4]

palabras.pop(indices[0])
palabras.pop(indices[1])
palabras.pop(indices[2])

print(palabras)
```

El resultado en consola vuelve a ser:

```
palabras.pop(indices[2])
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Si sé que el error me indica que el índice esta fuera de rango, sin embargo no entiendo porque es que esta fuera de rango, espero alguien me pueda ayudar, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explicación

En esta linea todo va bien:

```
palabras.pop(indices[0])
```

Se elimina el segundo item de la lista sin problemas y la lista queda en:

```
[['carro rojo'],[''],['avion'],['']]
```

Pero luego intentas eliminar el indice 2. Pero el indice 2 ya NO es `['']`, ya que si contás los items de la lista ahora, el item 2 sería `['avion']`. Este item se elimina y tu lista queda así:

```
[['carro rojo'],[''],['']]
```

Finalmente, intentas eliminar el item 4. Pero la lista solo tiene 3 items. Por lo tanto, tira error.

## Solución

Para que todos los items no se "corran de lugar" cada vez que borras uno de ellos, puedes obtener cada indice de la lista con `enumerate`, recorrer el resultado de enumerate con un bucle for y si el indice está en la lista de indices, entonces no hay que agregarlo.

Esto sería así con compresión de listas:

```
palabras = [palabra for index, palabra in enumerate(palabras) if(index not in indices)]
```

O así con el metodo "normal":

```
palabras2 = []

for index, palabra in enumerate(palabras):
    if(index not in indices):
        palabras2.append(palabra)

palabras = palabras2
```

## Bonus extra

Si lo que buscas es eliminar todas las sublistas que sean `['']` puedes aplicar algo similar a lo de arriba y eliminar todos esos casos sin necesidad de tener una lista de indices prearmada.

El método con compresión de listas sería así:

```
palabras = [palabra for palabra in palabras if(palabra != [''])]
```

Y el método con la forma "normal" asi:

```
palabras2 = []

for palabra in palabras:
    if(palabra != ['']):
        palabras2.append(palabra)

palabras = palabras2
```